# Real examples of a API Client class

Tags: php, api, client

I'm trying to find some simple examples of a PHP class accessing a distributed API.

Whenever I search for a PHP API client it gives way too much information on building the API itself and little in the way of real access methods beyond the curl examples.  A PHP class that includes a good curl method and a way to handle the requests would be nice.  I learn by example and lots of re-arranging.

I started with a construct to catch the usual connection settings:

```
private $hosts = array( URI_1,  URI_2,  URI_3);
private $users = array( USER_1, USER_2, USER_3);
private $pass =  array( PASS_1, PASS_2, PASS_3);

    public function __construct($request = array())
    {
        if (is_array($request)) {
        if(isset($request['hostname'])) {
            if(in_array($request['hostname'], $hosts)) {
                $this->input['hostname'] = $request['hostname'];
            }
        }
        if (isset($request['username'])) {
            if(in_array($request['username'], $users)) {
                $this->input['username'] = $request['username'];
            }
        }
        if (isset($request['password'])) {
            if (in_array($request['password'], $pass)) {
                $this->input['password'] = $request['password'];
            }
        }
        if (isset($this->input['hostname']) &&
                isset($this->input['username']) &&
                isset($this->input['password'])) {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Some simple examples of best practices would make this a lot easier.

Comment: if you don't want write a lot of code use SOAP or XMLRPC. wsdl file will provide every method. In REST you cannot do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try out [Guzzle](http://guzzlephp.org/):

> Guzzle takes the pain out of sending HTTP requests and the redundancy
>   out of creating web service clients.
>
> Guzzle is a framework that includes the tools needed to create a
>   robust web service client, including: Service descriptions for
>   defining the inputs and outputs of an API, resource iterators for
>   traversing paginated resources, batching for sending a large number of
>   requests as efficiently as possible.

Comment: It's a very good http wrapper. But still a wrapper. It does not turn API methods to class methods automatically.

Comment: you don't need to turn API methods to class methods. All of that is idle flow. Keep your code simple!

Comment: Read through the documentation.

Comment: Nice framework! And its on GitHub so I can explore from Eclipse .  I love the batching since the sources are distant. Thank you.

Comment: Bryan, welcome! This framework is used for Amazon Web Services SDK for PHP and is decent. Obviously it is not designed for some ppl from Bangladesh :-)